# Comma placement in form "this occurs...this is what results"

Tags: editing, punctuation

> This paradox results from a psychological alliance that forms between captor and captive leading to emotional bonding that is hard to break.

My knee-jerk instinct is to add a comma after "captive," but I can't justify its inclusion or omission.

I could change "leading" to ", which leads" or "and leads" and my problem goes away. But I come across this dilemma often and want to understand the right way to compose such a sentence.

Is there a rule for this (section 6.30 in the CMS seems to come closest to setting me straight), or is it just a stylistic preference?

I apologize for my lack of appropriate vocabulary in describing the specific parts of the sentence. My learning continues. Thank you.